# tableview not fetching core data date

Tags: swift, date, core-data, tableview, fetch

My code when button btn is touched it should save the date and then display it on the tableview cell. Nothing is happening when the button is called. The code work in storyboard but it did not work when I programmed it. It does not make any sense. The code is not producing any errors. The code should have the day and time on the cell if it works.

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource {
    
    
    var table = UITableView()
    var btn = UIButton()
    
    var foodItems = [Food]()
    var moc:NSManagedObjectContext!
    var appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        table.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
        moc = appDelegate?.persistentContainer.viewContext
        self.table.dataSource = self
        
        
        loadData()
        btn.backgroundColor = .systemTeal
        [table,btn].forEach{
            view.addSubview($0)
            $0.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        }
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            
            
            
            table.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.heightAnchor, multiplier: 0.5),
            table.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor, multiplier: 1),
            table.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor),
            table.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
            
            btn.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.heightAnchor, multiplier: 0.5),
            btn.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor, multiplier: 1),
            btn.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor),
            btn.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor)
            
            
            
        ])
        btn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(addFoodToDatabase(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        
    }
    
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        loadData()
    }
    
    func loadData(){
        // 1
        let foodRequest:NSFetchRequest<Food> = Food.fetchRequest()
        
        // 2
        let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "added", ascending: false)
        foodRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]
        
        // 3
        do {
            try foodItems = moc.fetch(foodRequest)
            
        }catch {
            print("Could not load data")
        }
        
        // 4
        self.table.reloadData()
    }
    
    
    
    @objc   func addFoodToDatabase(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let foodItem = Food(context: moc)
        foodItem.added = NSDate() as Date
        
        
        
        appDelegate?.saveContext()
        
        loadData()
        
    }
    
    
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return foodItems.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)
        
        // 1
        let foodItem = foodItems[indexPath.row]
        
        // 2
        let foodType = foodItem.type
        cell.textLabel?.text = foodType
        
        // 3
        let foodDate = foodItem.added!
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MMMM d yyyy, hh:mm"
        
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = dateFormatter.string(from: foodDate)
        
        
        
        return cell
    }
    
    
    
    
    
}
```

[link to github](https://github.com/redrock34/tableview)

Comment: What is bin?  Or a button?

Comment: edited code above plus added GitHub.

Comment: Does it save at all in Core Data? Like, when you restart your app, do you see the entry in your tableView?

Comment: no it does not.